Redshift COPY with JSON PATH Case Sensitivity
I want to copy a file from S3 to Redshift. Content is in camelCase:
{"accountId":{"S":"1acb4"}}

Redshift columns are in all lowercase. This is marshalled Dynamo JSON, so I am using a JSON PATHs file for copying:
{"jsonpaths": ["$.accountId.S"]}

I have read across various sources on the internet that using a JSON PATHs file eliminates the issue of non-matching case, but I am still getting NULLs when running my COPY statement as such:
COPY destination.table
FROM 's3://mybucket/myfile'
IAM_ROLE 'myarn'
JSON 's3://path/to/jsonpathsfile.json'

How can I get the camelCase JSON to load into Redshift by using COPY? 'ignorecase' is not allowed to be used when using a JSON PATHs file, but I need the JSON PATHs file to unmarshall the DynamoDB JSON.

{"accountId":{"S:"1acb4"}} That's not a valid dictionary -- the second colon should be outside the quotes, not inside.  And the quotes are mismatched.  This can't be the real value

Good point. I have adjusted the code to reflect the correct quotations in the example. This was not the source of the issue however

Have you tried enabling cases sensitive identifiers?
set enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true;

It may not be the issue but a good place to start.

This solved the issue. When I recreated my table, enclosing my case sensitive column name in double quotation marks, I was able to load the case sensitive keys into columns in my table. Thank you
